# Check if a point lies on the boundary of two raster cells

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have 25-km raster grid and a point. If I plot the point on the raster, it falls ~on the borderof two adjacent raster cells. I don't how to generate a sample data for this specific case but here's a visualisation of what I am taking about.

[image]

Is there any way I can detect for a group of points how many points are cases like this which could like very close to the border of two adjacent raster cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the function `on_border` that I show below.
Its arguments are SpatRaster `r`, coordinates `x` and `y`, and a `tolerance` for comparing real numbers.

```
on_border <- function(r, x, y, tolerance = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) {
    v <- h <- (x >= xmin(r)) & (x <= xmax(r)) & (y >= ymin(r)) & (y <= ymax(r))
    v[v] <- ((x[v] - xmin(r)) %% res(r)[1]) < tolerance
    h[h] <- ((y[h] - ymin(r)) %% res(r)[2]) < tolerance
    h | v
}
```

Illustration

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=5, ncol=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5, vals=1:25)
x <- c(1, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 4.5)
y <- c(1, 1.5, 2.5, 5, 5.2)

on_border(r, x, y)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

plot(r); lines(r); points(x,y, xpd=TRUE, pch=20, cex=1.5)
```

[image]

To get the distance to the nearest border

```
to_border <- function(r, x, y) {
    i <- (x >= xmin(r)) & (x <= xmax(r)) & (y >= ymin(r)) & (y <= ymax(r))
    d <- rep(NA, length(i))
    d[i] <- (x[i] - xmin(r)) %% res(r)[1]
    d[i] <- pmin(d[i], (y[i] - ymin(r)) %% res(r)[2])
    d
}

to_border(r, x, y)
#[1] 0.0 0.5 0.0 0.0  NA
```

In principle, you could also create lines from the raster, and do a relate query like I show below, but that is *really inefficient*.

```
pts <- vect(cbind(x, y), crs=crs(r))
rlns <- aggregate(as.lines(r))
relate(pts, rlns, "intersects")
#      [,1]
#[1,]  TRUE
#[2,] FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE
#[4,]  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE
```

But if you wanted the distance to the border, you may need to do something like this.

```
distance(pts, rlns)
#     [,1]
#[1,]  0.0
#[2,]  0.5
#[3,]  0.0
#[4,]  0.0
#[5,]  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the raster extent, dimensions and resolution, you can calculate the coordinates of the cells, like

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.17
r <- rast(nrows=20, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin = 0, ymax = 10)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(r))) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(r))) {
    if(i %% 2 != 0 & j %% 2 != 0) {
      print(paste(i, j))
      r[i,j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
for (i in seq_len(nrow(r))) {
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(r))) {
    if(i %% 2 == 0 & j %% 2 == 0) {
      print(paste(i, j))
      r[i,j] <- 1
    }
  }
}

terra::plot(r, axes = TRUE)

# a few points
p <- rbind(c(1,1), c(2.3,3), c(3, 4), c(5.5,5.5)) |>
  terra::vect("points")
terra::plot(p, add = TRUE, pch = 12)
```

[image]

Now the calculations. Dimension and resolution:

```r
dim(r)
#> [1] 20 10  1
res(r)
#> [1] 1.0 0.5
```

Let's calculate the coordinates of the cells (here just X):

```r
xcoords <- vector(mode="list", length=dim(r)[1]-1)
for (i in seq_along(xcoords)) {
 xcoords[[i]] <- as.numeric(ext(r)[1])+i*res(r)[1]
}
```

And finally chceck, which points are located exactly on the xcoords:

```r
xx <- geom(p)[,"x"]

which(xx %in% xcoords)
#> [1] 1 3
```

Having raster dimensions you can create lines corresponding to grid, and do spatial intersects, see `sf::st_make_grid()`.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>